# Refugee in France, travelling to the USA as a tourist?

Tags: visas, usa, france, esta, refugees

I am a refugee in France with a French travel passport. I want to visit the USA as a tourist. I don't know how to start. Should I take an interview appointment at the US embassy in France? Maybe I can do the ESTA visa electronically and buy my tickets?

Comment: Is your travel document a «Titre de voyage pour réfugié (Convention du 28 juillet 1951)» ?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes! Do you have any information?

Comment: It is really important for me: please give me an advice I dont know what to do

Comment: In that case you can find your answer in the link above. You can just go apply for a visa.